# Bayesian linear regression in WEKA

Tags: machine-learning, weka, linear-regression

Does WEKA have **Bayesian linear regression** implementation?

Microsoft Azure has Bayesian linear regression https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn906022.aspx which in my case performs better that linear regression of WEKA.

Answer (score 1):

NO, I as per the **weka** documentation, it has only **Bayesian Logistic Regression**. I suggest using linear regression classifier only with weka.